# how to add string in result string data

Tags: c#, string

i have a db value

```
    ╔══════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ SatuanID ║  Address   ║ ParentAddr  ║
    ╠══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║  100     ║     1      ║      0      ║
    ║  101     ║     2      ║      1      ║
    ║  201     ║     4      ║      2      ║
    ║  102     ║     5      ║      1      ║
    ║  202     ║     6      ║      2      ║
    ║  203     ║     7      ║      5      ║
    ╚══════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

here is my code to load data to string

```
public string child_list, myStr, ipList, childAdd, sub_child, sprtChild;

string sqlChild = "";
sqlChild = string.Format("select Address ,IpSlave , ( Select COUNT (*) From SatuanKawan where ParentAddr = 1) AS Count From SatuanKawan where ParentAddr = 1");
//         sql = string.Format("select * from SatuanKawan");
DataTable dtChild = CGlobalVar.dbaseBMSOps.GetDataTable(sqlChild);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
List<string> listIp = new List<string>();
List<string> listSubChild = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow rowChild in dtChild.Rows)
{
    count = (string)rowChild["Count"].ToString();
    childAdd = (string)rowChild["Address"].ToString();
    list.Add(rowChild["Address"].ToString());
    listIp.Add(rowChild["IpSlave"].ToString());
    string sqlSubChild = "";
    sqlSubChild = string.Format("select Address From SatuanKawan where ParentAddr = {0}", childAdd);
    DataTable dtSubChild = CGlobalVar.dbaseBMSOps.GetDataTable(sqlSubChild);
    foreach (DataRow rowSubChild in dtSubChild.Rows)
    {
        listSubChild.Add(rowSubChild["Address"].ToString());
    }

}

sub_child = string.Join(",", listSubChild.ToArray());
```

now the childAdd value is **2** and **5**

and subchild value is **4,6,7**

i use foreach again because i want the result subchild value is **+4,6_+7_**

string "+" mean :

in query `"select Address From SatuanKawan where ParentAddr = {0}", childAdd`
childAdd value is **2** and **5**

so the value is **4,6** and **7**

string "," mean separate between childAdd value

So **"+"** mean +4,6_+7_

string **"_"** is separate between 4,6 and 7

so the value result is **+4,6_+7_**

how to make string subChild result be **+4,6_+7_** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var sql = "SELECT Address, IpSlave, ParentAddr FROM SatuanKawan;";
using (var dt = CGlobalVar.dbaseBMSOps.GetDataTable(sql))
{
    var data =
        dt.Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => new
            {
                Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                IpSlave = dr["IpSlave"].ToString(),
                ParentAddr = dr["ParentAddr"].ToString(),
            })
            .ToArray();

    var lookUp = data.ToLookup(x => x.ParentAddr);

    sub_child =
        String.Join("",
            lookUp["1"]
                .Select(x => String.Format("+{0}_",
                    String.Join(",",
                        lookUp[x.Address]
                            .Select(y => y.Address)))));
}
```

The result I got from your data was:

```
+4,6_+7_
```

Comment: yes it works for me too, when add new child, the result is works too.

Comment: but im newbie, i dont understand your flow algorithms, do you can explain that for me?

Comment: @Antares - Which part or parts don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question, but it seems to me that all you need to do is to replace the last instance of "," in the sub_child string by "*+", then add a "+" at the start of the string and a "*" at the end.

In other words, add the following code at the end of your posted code:

```
int index = sub_child.LastIndexOf(",");
sub_child = String.Format("+{0}_", sub_child.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, "_+));
```

Comment: when i try with your code the result is right `+4,6_+7_` but when i try to add child in Address 5 the value is `+4,6,7_+8_` so the value must `+4,6_+7,8_`

Comment: The poor wording of your question made it difficult to provide you with the exact solution. Enigmativity's code should work for you. You might want to check [lambda expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes) to help understand his solution.